# Creating multiple rows from single row on specified conditions in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to implement Null check. For e.g :

```
Col_A | Col_B | Col_C | Col_D
null  | boy   | null  | dust
```

Then I want output as :

```
Col_A | Col_B | Col_C | Col_D | New_Col
null  | boy   | null  | dust  | Col_A failed null check
null  | boy   | null  | dust  | Col_D failed null check
```

What is the proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t.*
      ,concat(elt(e.pos+1,'Col_A','Col_B','Col_C','Col_D'),' failed null check') as New_Col
from   mytable t lateral view posexplode (array(Col_A,Col_B,Col_C,Col_D)) e
where  e.val is null
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to hive, so can you please elaborate what 'elt' did ?

Comment: `elt` returns the element in the Nth position (`e.pos` starts from 0)

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `union all`:

```
select Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, Col_D, 'Col_A failed NULL check' as new_col
from t
where Col_A is null
union all
select Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, Col_D, 'Col_B failed NULL check' as new_col
from t
where Col_B is null
union all
select Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, Col_D, 'Col_C failed NULL check' as new_col
from t
where Col_C is null
union all
select Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, Col_D, 'Col_D failed NULL check' as new_col
from t
where Col_D is null;
```

This is rather brute force.  If you have lots of columns you can generate the SQL using a spreadsheet.  This also requires a separate scan for each subquery.

Comment: This will not work as we have many checks and around 10 million records.

Comment: @ManishVishnoi . . . This will work, you just have to write the code.  In any case, it is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  You asked about 2 columns and one type of check.  If you have another question, then ask it as *another* question.